# Push, how to unsubscribe from getting push notifications?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push

I am working with `Parse.com`. I do not want to receive general notifications, I tried it in `onCreate()`, but it didn't happen.

**ParseApplication**

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Initialize Crash Reporting.
    ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this, "-", "-");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
  }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.e("com.parse.push", "unscribe");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unscribe exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bottom.smart.testpush" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.bottom.smart.testpush.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.bottom.smart.testpush.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.bottom.smart.testpush.ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.bottom.smart.testpush" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".Receiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is there an error when you try to unsubscribe. Log output will be useful here.

Comment: Made question more comprehensive.

Comment: @IgorFilippov thanks for unswer. I have not error. I want do not receive general push notifications. But i still get push

Comment: @Darpan thanks for answer. I do not want to receive general notifications, but i still get it

Comment: do you have the channel name you are subscribing to? You are passing `""` in channel name in function `unsubscribeInBackground()`. Provide your channel's name there..

Comment: @Darpan no i have not channel. if i start this app i getting general push notifications. I want not to receive general push notifications

Comment: unsubscribing is just for unsubscribing from a specific channel (in your case channel ""), not from the push service in generell. either you just send messages too a specific channel, everybody subscribes or you delete the accout on parse.

Comment: @Rithe if i currectly understand you. Evrybody when start app subscribe in general channel and i cant unscribe user in general channel?

Comment: yes, because if you don't define a channel for your pushes, you are broadcasting and everybody who initialized parse with your key and app id will receive this push notification.

Comment: @Rithe aa.. thanks for answer